# Convert a 2D matrix to stringarray of columns (java)

Tags: java

I do not have much knowledge of ArrayLists in java. I need a solution for the following problem: how to make an array[] of the columns of a 2D matrix. The inputfile is:

V G V VV G V V V
E F V VF E V E V
V V V VV V V V V
A A V VA G V A D
V D V VD E V V V
A V V VV V V A V

and the desired format for the Stringarray `liner` (see below) is:

{"VEVAVA","GFVADV","VVVVVV","VVVFVVVAVDVV","GEVGEV","VVVVVV","VEVAVA","VVVDVV"}

The code I have is:

```java
    ArrayList<String[]> mat = new ArrayList<String[]>();


Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("internal2"));
String[] liner = new String[m];
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

    Scanner colReader2 = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
    while(colReader2.hasNext())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<m; i++) {
            liner[i] = colReader2.next();
//System.out.println(liner[i]);
            mat.add(liner);
            }

    }
//        scan.nextLine();
}
```

The purpose of this is that I want to search these strings in `liner`. Now the program seems to only give `liner` like this:
{"A","V","V","VV","V","V","A","V"}
which is the last row of the inputfile. I hope you can help me.

**Edit**

My code continues with:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-G]+");
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[V]+");

String[][] matrix4 = mat.toArray(new String[n][m]);

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

    StringBuffer sf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        sf.append(matrix4[j][i]);

    }

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sf.toString());
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(sf.toString());

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("R");
    } else if (matcher2.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Q");
    }

}
```

So for a columnstring in `liner` containing at least 1 occurence of `A-G` an `R` has to be printed. And for a columnstring containing only `V`'s it has to print `Q`. The output then should be:

```
R
R
Q
R
R
Q
R
R
```

But this is not what I get. Does anyone of you know what I am doing wrong?

**Solved:**

I had to get the `null`s out of liner by using `Arrays.fill(liner, "");`

Comment: What I get is: R
R
R
R
R
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Scanner.next()` only scans characters until the next whitespace. If you want to scan a whole line use `Scanner.nextLine()`, which should give you `"V G V VV G V V V"`. To remove the whitespace between the characters use `String.replaceAll("\s", "")` on that.

**Update:** sorry, I misunderstood your question.

To get your desired output, change `liner[i] = colReader2.next()` to `liner[i] += colReader2.next()`

That should append a character to the array entry instead of replacing it.

**Update #2:** I tested your code snippets and found some problems.

- `liner[i]` isn't initialized with an empty String which leads to the output `nullVEVAVA` and so on ... I didn't check for that, sorry.
- you don't need to use two Scanners, one is enough.
- `mat.add(liner)` only adds the reference to your array, so if you change that array, these changes will also be visible in the ArrayList
- in general, it would be better to first parse your input file and *then* create an array, because you don't have to know the dimensions
- assuming you want an ArrayList of an Array of Strings holding the columns of the (I assume that it's not jagged) input, this should do it (well, at least it gives me the desired output):

  ```
  ArrayList<String[]> input = new ArrayList<String[]>();

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input"));

  // read the input
  while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      input.add(sc.nextLine().split("\\s"));
  }

  sc.close();

  // this only works if your input isn't jagged!
  String[][] mat = new String[input.get(0).length][];

  // transform your matrix from [line][column] to [column][line]
  for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < input.get(i).length; j++) {
          if (mat[j] == null) {
              mat[j] = new String[input.size()];
          }
          if (mat[j][i] == null) {
              mat[j][i] = "";
          }
          mat[j][i] += input.get(i)[j];
      }
  }

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-G]+");
  Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[V]+");

  for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
          sb.append(mat[i][j]);
      }

      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb.toString());
      Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(sb.toString());

      if (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println("R");
      } else if (matcher2.matches()) {
          System.out.println("Q");
      }
  }
  ```

If this still doesn't help, I'm sorry, but my time is as precious as yours and I'm sure you can solve many problems by doing some decent research. However, if you get *really* stuck, just come back and ask another question and we will willingly help you out ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question, so please check and help me further.

Comment: What does your `liner` look like? Please also post your actual output, not just the desired. And (for your next question) don't change your question until your work is done but rather open a new one, if you get stuck again.

Comment: liner prints: nullVEVAVA
nullVFVADV
nullVVVVVV
nullVVVFVVVAVDVV
nullVEVGEV
nullVVVVVV
nullVEVAVA
nullVVVDVV

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder in the array list and append to it. I guess the size of the matrix is known before you start accepting values? Not sure what you are expecting from the

```
List<StringBuilder[]> mat = new ArrayList<StringBuilder[]>();//better to declare as list, array list is 1 implementation


Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("internal2"));
int col = 0;    
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    col = 0;
    Scanner colReader2 = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
    while(colReader2.hasNext())
    {

        if(mat.size() < (col + 1)){
            mat.add(new StringBuilder());
        }
        //mat.get(col).substring(mat.get(col).length() - 1);
        mat.get(col).append(colReader2.next())
        }

}
//        scan.nextLine();
```

}